# How to get sum of string data in SQL?

Tags: sql, time, sum, hour

I have a table with column name 'Working_hours', column type is String and data of that column looks like below.
I want to sum of those data.
Is there any way to achieve it or any idea.
thanks in advance

```
0:00:11
0:00:08
0:00:01
0:00:29
0:01:25
0:00:06
0:00:12
0:00:26
0:00:01
0:01:41
0:00:01
```

Comment: what's your dbms?

Comment: Cast as interval hour to second. SUM(). (And use proper data types from now on.)

Comment: Sorry for my lack of information its Sql database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
convert(char(20),dateadd(second,SUM 
( 
DATEPART(hh,(convert(datetime,Working_hours,1))) * 3600 +
DATEPART(mi, (convert(datetime,Working_hours,1))) * 60 + 
DATEPART(ss,(convert(datetime,Working_hours,1)))),0),108
)
AS Working_hours
FROM tblTime
```

You can use this Query....In Sql server..

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which product this is for.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly ans and i am using sql database.

Comment: @Sohel Rreza . . . You should accept this answer if it works for you...

Answer (score 0):

convert this to epoch time.

for **mssql**

```
select sum(DATEDIFF(s, '1900-01-01 00:00:00', cast(time_column as datetime))) from table
```

result is sum in seconds.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which product this is for.

Answer (score 0):

that depends a bit on what database you are using

generally you have to convert or cast to time and sum then. Eg.g postgresql:

```
SELECT SUM(fieldname::time) FROM table
```

The `::time` does the casting to time.

Microsoft sql-server (don't have one at hand right now so take with a grain of salt):

```
SELECT sum(CONVERT( TIME, fieldname )) FROM table
```

If you have some other database look up how to cast or convert a string to a time...

Comment: Thanks for your kind response , i am using sql database.